# Temphire (Angular) does not support deep links and refresh?

Tags: breeze

When playing with the Temphire app, I noticed that when I try to refresh a page by hitting F5, the application shows a blank page ! (ngViewport is not rendered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution... it was an IIS issue, needed to rewrite urles in order to keep it working :

```
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```